# Get value from a var

Tags: c#, sqlite

I've got this piece of code and I need to get the value of a specific column from the database.

```
using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
{
    var sql = "select * from " + tablename + " where ID = " + itemid;
    var data1 = cnn.QuerySingle(sql)
}
```

And I know that It can be done like this

```
string s = data1.ColumnName;
```

But is there a way for me to set the column reference programmatically as below?

```
string test = "Column1";
string s = data1.test;
```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: ok, but this function will only be for internal use and won't be exposed to user input at all.

Comment: @catalyst6 attacks can come from internal users; it is so absurdly easy to get this right (see the second part of my answer) that there is no excuse for being lazy here

Comment: that does not matter. bad, insecure, error-prone code is bad, insecure and error-prone no matter where you use it. there is no reason _not_ to use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like Dapper. In which case, you can cast the row from this to `IDictionary<string, object>`, and use the indexer.

```
var map = (IDictionary<string,object>)data1;
var value = map[columnName];
```

Note that the comments are right, and you should parameterize this query. You can't parameterize the table name, though:

```
var sql = "select * from " + tablename + " where ID = @itemid";
var data1 = cnn.QuerySingle(sql, new {itemid});
```

Comment: You may at least validate that `tableName` contains only "safe" characters. Otherwise the code is still open for SQL injection.

Comment: @KlausGütter IMO table names must be allow-listed; the list of table names should usually be pretty stable